# Trying to persist an entity with @ManyToOne mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I'm trying to persist a *User* that has a mapping @ManyToOne with *UserStatus*

but when I do the code below, the hibernate throws *PropertyValueException*

```
user.setStatus(new UserStatus(1));
em.persist(user); // ou session.saveAndUpdate(user);
```

to work I have to do this way:

```
user.setStatus(em.getReference(UserStatus.class, 1));
em.persist(user); // ou session.saveAndUpdate(user);
```

I know the first way is possible, but what I don't know is whether I need to configure or call another method (I've already tried saveAndUpdate from Session and still the same)

Does anyone have any idea?

The error message is:

```
not-null property references a null or transient value
```

the mapping

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_status_id", nullable = false)
public UserStatus getStatus() {
    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error means "*you are referencing a null (not persisted) object*" and you have to choice: remove `nullable` or set `@Cascade` so `UserStatus` will per persisted when you do `em.persist(user)`

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_status_id", nullable = false)
@Cascade(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public UserStatus getStatus() {
    return status;
}
```

EDIT: After various test, using `getReference()` is the right way to proceed because `new UserStatus(1)` go for error and should be substituted as `getReference(UserStatus.class,ID)` to return a proxied instance of UserStatus. Proxied object doesn't hit on database, so SELECT is avoided and the only field setted on UserStatus proxy is the ID, necessary to resolve @ManyToOne relation!

Some useful answer: [When to use EntityManager.find() vs EntityManager.getReference()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607532/when-to-use-entitymanager-find-vs-entitymanager-getreference)
[What is the difference between EntityManager.find() and EntityManger.getReference()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482141/what-is-the-difference-between-entitymanager-find-and-entitymanger-getreferenc)

Comment: the relation entity is already persisted on the database, however the object isn’t attached, I don’t want to do a SELECT just to make a INSERT

Comment: so just try to remove `nullable`

Comment: if I remove nullable the hibernate tries to INSERT null in this column, which is NOT NULL on the database

Comment: you have to do a SELECT because Hibernate - with error `not-null property references a null or transient value` doesn't allow transient objects (created with `new`)

Comment: It's not mandatory. Doing the getReference doesn't make any SELECT statement and it works fine. But I know there's a solution for this, just setting the ID on the association

Comment: `getReference()` just set ID on the association because it's return a UserStatus proxy without hit database (in proxied object just the ID is retrieved): `getReference()` is the right way to do what you wrote on your last comment (_But I know there's a solution for this, just setting the ID on the association_)! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607532/when-to-use-entitymanager-find-vs-entitymanager-getreference  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482141/what-is-the-difference-between-entitymanager-find-and-entitymanger-getreferenc

Comment: I know that, but in the company I work we do "user.setStatus(new UserStatus(1))" without the need to create a proxy and it works fine, I already asked how it is done, but no one knows the answer.