# Accessing spring boot data jpa entity in filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, servlet-filters

At the moment I'm trying to convert my servlet-based application to a spring boot application with controllers. After I set up a filter I encountered an "could not initialize proxy - no Session"-Exception, when accessing an entities function. (Here: The users method "isAdmin").

I set up a filter like this:

```
public class AdminFilter implements Filter {

  @Autowired
  UserRepository userRepository;

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest aRequest, ServletResponse aResponse, FilterChain aFilterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
            User u = userRepository.getOne(5l).orElse(null);
            System.out.println(u.isAdmin());
    aFilterChain.doFilter(aRequest, aResponse);
  }

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this,
            filterConfig.getServletContext());
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
  }
}
```

Implemented the Filter interface and addded the Filter in an @Configuration tagged class to register the filter to "/admin":

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfiguration {
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean adminRegistration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(new AdminFilter());
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/admin/*");
    return registration;
   }
}
```

The Autowiring-Support is enabled by the following statement:

```
SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this,
        filterConfig.getServletContext());
```

I tried to add @Transactional to the method and also added the OpenSessionInViewFilter - without success.

In my Controller-Beans (@Controller) I can access the function of the entity retrieved from an autowired repository without any problems.

The function just returns a value from the user entity:

```
public boolean isAdmin() {
    return admin;
}
```

Any ideas why I'm getting the error and how to fix it?

A stracktrace cut:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:148) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:266) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at de.seeme.web.persistence.User_$$_jvst43d_a.isAdmin(User_$$_jvst43d_a.java) ~[bin/:na]
```

Greetings

gemorra

Comment: Can you share your @Configuration class?

Comment: What is  `isAdmin()` method doing? Can you share more details? And I do believe you can create a more robust finder method in `UserRepository`.

Comment: @IssamELATIF I updated my question, but the config file is empty except the filter registration...

Comment: @AntonNovopashin I updated the question. It's just returning a boolean value from the entity. What do you mean with "create a more robust finder method"?

Comment: How your entityManager is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

damn. Tried it with userRepository.find(id) and everything works fine.

With getOne you will just get a reference to the entity containing only the id (for existence checks or similiar).

[Difference between CrudRepository findOne() and JpaRepository getOne()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218762/difference-between-crudrepository-findone-and-jparepository-getone)