# JPA - TransientPropertyValueException while saving object with only ID

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an object called invoice that has a field which is a complex object

```
public class Invoice {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_site_to")
    private Site siteTo;
}

public class Site {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id_site")
    private long id;

    private String description;
    ...
}
```

in a point of my code, I create an Invoice from a DTO. The so-created invoice contains a Site without all fields populated but only the ID.
When I try to save this invoice instance (with JPA repository), I get

`org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value`

even if the site Id exists in the database. There's a way to perform this save without having to first get the site from the database with a select?

Comment: can u povide complete stacktrace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `EntityManager` you can try to call `getReference()`, refer [What is the difference between EntityManager.find() and EntityManger.getReference()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5482477/3405171) for details.

With Hibernate's `Session` you can use `load()` as well.

All this methods return proxies without access to the database.

**One note**

With Hibernate's `Session` I use your way of setting an association by object with the `id` only. Everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change the creation order, this error means that you are creating a reference to an object that it's not created still. Create the Site and then the Invoice.

Comment: He already has the `Site` in the database. He wants to set a fake `Site` with filling `id` only, without loading the whole `Site` from the database.